# choose numbers of different lengths

Tags: python, slice

I am using Python have a list of 2 columns with lots of white space in between, e.g.:

```
TEXT           123.34645
TEXT            13.35372
TEXT             0.55532
TEXT            11.60538
```

I want my python code to grab the numbers on the right.

At first I was doing this, by going line by line and grabbing line[15:24] or whatever - but then I realised that some of the numbers were different lengths, and so this wasn't going to work.

What's the correct way to do this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> 'TEXT           123.34645\n'.split()
['TEXT', '123.34645']
```

The default form of `.split()` splits on arbitrary-width whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace. In the above example, the `\n` at the end of the line is ignored.

If your text contains whitespace too, use [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with a limit:

```
>>> 'TEXT WITH WHITESPACE           123.34645'.rsplit(None, 1)
['TEXT WITH WHITESPACE', '123.34645']
```

`None` tells `.rsplit()` (or `.split()`) to split on variable-width whitespace, and `1` is the maximum number of splits to make.

Answer (score 2):

`.split()` is the answer.

So when you read your lines in from a text file, apply the `split()` method to each line.

```
In [1]: f = open('test.txt')   # test.txt contains the text indicated in your question

In [2]: for line in f:
   ...:     result = line.split()
   ...:     print result
   ...:
['TEXT', '123.34645']
['TEXT', '13.35372']
['TEXT', '0.55532']
['TEXT', '11.60538']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        text, number = re.search(r'([\w\s]+)\s+([\d.]+)',line).groups()
        print(number)
```

Produces

```
123.34645
13.35372
0.55532
11.60538
>>>
```